# Will I need a power converter for my laptop? (U.S. based.) to Philippines?

Tags: gear, power, philippines

It's a standard U.S. Dell laptop.  I'll be in Manila, mostly in a hotel for a conference.

Comment: What they said. BUT you may wish to pack some form of spike and anti surge protector OR do due diligence on how good the Manila power quality is. It may be excellent for all I know - but some major cities are not. Many modern switch mode power supplies are relatively immune to spikes and surges - but a spike suppressor can be good insurance.

Comment: What everyone else said: I have not seen a 120-only laptop in at least 19 years.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mains_electricity_by_country) has some pretty extensive information about power standards around the world.  According to this information, the Philippines uses types A, B, and C plugs:

[image: Type A Plug]
[image: Type B Plug]
[image: Type C Plug]

However, it operates at 220V, 60Hz.  The US uses 120V 60Hz.  So while your US plugs (Type A & B) will physically fit into the sockets in the Philippines, you need to be sure your devices are electronically compatible with 220V.

Most modern electronics (laptops, for instance) have auto-sensing power supplies, which accept 110V-240V, and adjust accordingly. Here's an image of my laptop power supply, with the relevant info circled (Which reads **INPUT: 100-240V~1.5A 50-60Hz**):

[image: Lenovo power supply]

Some older electronics will have a switch you can toggle between 120V and 220V.  You'll need to check your individual devices to be sure.

It's unclear to me from this information if you may find yourself in a situation with only a Type C plug.  You may want to get a Type C to Type A adapter such as [this one](http://amzn.to/1fltqB2) just to be safe.
[image: Type C to Type A adaptor]

Answer (score 8):

Firstly, look on your laptop's power unit/base/charger.  Usually the fine print will give you a range - e.g. Rated input AC100-240V or something similar.

If it matches the range required, then no power converter is required for you to be able to use it there.

So, then it's down to the adapter (plug) and the voltage in the Philippines.  You can use this [list of mains electricity by country](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mains_electricity_by_country) to determine that they use types A,B,C, running at 220V and 60Hz.  Note that if you have a type A/B plug as in the US, which is only rated at 125V, you should not try to use it in the Philippines without a converter.

Most modern electronics will have 50-60hz/100-240V support, but do check to be sure.

To compare, **the plug WILL look very similar**, as seen in the chart below, but you do need to **make sure your device can handle the different voltage requirements.**

[image: Plug chart from 110220volts.com]

Answer (score 6):

Later model Dell laptops have power supplies rated 110 - 240V, so you won't need a converter since power in the [Philippines is 220V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mains_electricity_by_country) but the plug may not match, which means that you may need a power plug adapter like [this one](http://www.110220volts.com/MU5.html?gclid=CMaeoIyU3LwCFfM7OgodOUkA9g) to be able to plug it in.

I would though check the Power Supply as to actual power ratings.

Comment: Great answer.  I like the pictures in the other one, plus it's a little more thorough.  But thank you very much for answering.  Your tip on modern Dells is super heplful.

Comment: @Gn13l Then you should upvote the answer(s).

Answer (score 2):

I no longer have a Dell but it was rated 110-240V and 50-60Hz (multi-voltage) so it can handle the 220V in the Philippines.  I used it in Australia and just needed to pack an Australian adapter.  Your Dell likely has a plug with three prongs (grounded) so I'd suggest packing a three-pronged adapter; also pack a two-pronged (ungrounded) adapter just in case.  This post has a few references that might be helpful:
http://packinglighttravel.com/travel-tech/electrical-issues-travellers/

Comment: Is that site yours?